# vba - copy-paste the last n non-blank column in the next blank column - on multiple same-formatted sheets

Tags: vba, copy-paste, nonblank

- I have 4 sheets that are identical in format (same number of columns with different data).
- On each sheet, I would like to copy the 6 last non-blank columns and paste them in the next 6 blank columns.
- that should be done on all 4 sheets at once (i.e. not running the macro sheet after sheet).

I found multiple pieces of the answer but I am struggling putting them together (I have no knowledge in VBA).

Thank you a lot

Comment: I tried this- but this only works on the current sheet I am on. And I would like to make it work on all the sheets following the first ones (i.e. selected sheets). If I add one sheet or that I change the name of an existing sheet, I would like the macro to loop through the new/renamed sheet as well... 

Sub CopyRange()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").Row

Range(Cells(1, LastCol), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Select
Selection.Copy

Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code copy the last not-empty row (6 columns) and paste them to the next empty row (6 columns). However this code only work if your sheets name have the number 1 to 4 in the end. 
(Remember to change the sheetname in the code if your sheet names are not "sheet1","sheet2","sheet3" and "sheet4") Hope it helps you or other  (:

```
Sub A()
Dim count As Integer
Dim sheetname As String

sheetname = sheet

For x = 1 To 4

sheetname = "sheet" & x

Worksheets(sheetname).Activate

count = 1

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(count, 1).Value = ""

  count = count + 1

Loop


ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(count - 1, 1).Select


ActiveCell.Resize(, 6).Copy

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you M. Kjaer.
it says there's an application defined or object defined error.
When I debug, the following highlights "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(count - 1, 1).Select"
Apologies if this is a silly question. I tried other options, but could not see what is wrong...

Comment: Hmmmm. That is weird... It works by me. Are you sure that you have changed the name of your sheets or changed the code so it matches? You Also have to have 4 sheets or correct the code part "For x = 1 To 4" to "For x = 1 To 3" or how many sheets you have :)

Comment: it works now - thank you so much for your help M. Kjaer

Comment: No problem. Thank you :)